# MVC3 Model Binding Issue with EditorTemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, model-binding

Having some issues trying to model bind to my view model.

The basic viewmodel is thus:

```
public class RegistrationVM
{
    public TravelHistoryVM TravelHistory {get;set;}
    public UserDetailVM UserDetails {get;set;}
    public ICollection<HandsetDevicesVM> ExistingDevices {get;set;}
}
```

A wrapper for 3 further viewmodels, each containing the usual band of strings, ints and bools. Ignore the collection of HandsetDevicesVM for now.

I have the following view (sample for clarity)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TravelHistory.DoNotTravel)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.TravelHistory.DoNotTravel)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserDetails, "UserDetailsHidden")
}
```

The 'TravelHistory' object is being bound fine, no issues.
The 'UserDetails' object is always just null when data is posted back.

The template is definitely rendering, I can tell from the HTML. The template itself is given below:

```
@model Foo.Bar.UserDetailVM
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Surname)
@* etc etc *@
```

The HTML generated is

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Email Address field is required." id="UserDetails_EmailAddress" name="UserDetails.EmailAddress" type="hidden" value="stack@overflow.com" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." id="UserDetails_FirstName" name="UserDetails.FirstName" type="hidden" value="Stack" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Surname field is required." id="UserDetails_Surname" name="UserDetails.Surname" type="hidden" value="Overflow" />
```

I am using this EditorTemplate on another view with no issues (it binds to that viewmodel no problem).

Finally, using Fiddler I can ascertain the information is being posted.. I think

```
UserDetails.EmailAddress=stack%40overflow.com.test&UserDetails.FirstName=stack&UserDetails.Surname=overflow
```

Any ideas? Where should I be concentrating my debugging efforts?

Edit1: just noticed this from the ModelState object

```
AttemptedValue: 'Foo.Bar.UserDetailVM'
```

So it seems it is trying to bind the string value 'Foo.Bar.UserDetailVM' to the object and (obviously) failing.

Edit2:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Travel(RegistrationVM model)
```

As requested, the action I am POSTing to

Edit3:

Ahhh.. OK going back a stage, this is the action method that serves up the View

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Travel(PreRegistrationVM model)
{
    if (TempData["PreRegistrationVM"] != null)
    {
        model = (PreRegistrationVM)TempData["PreRegistrationVM"];
    }
    var newModel = new RegistrationVM(model);
    return View(newModel);
}
```

This is what I have been using (and thus has been part of the process that does not work). Essentially the information from a prior step is saved in the TempData and picked up in this method. It is then used to instantiate the VM as above. At this point (if I insert a breakpoint here), the model is populated with data as I expect.

If I amend that to the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Travel(PreRegistrationVM model)
{
    var newModel = new RegistrationVM 
    {
        FirstName = "Stack",
        Surname = "Overflow"
    };
    return View(newModel);
}
```

It binds as expected. Is TempData the culprit here?

Comment: Could you show the exact signature of the action you are posting this form to?

Comment: 1 - Im assuming you are posting back into a `RegistrationVM`? 2 - Also, why are you using an EditorTemplate for this when the user doesnt have anything to edit? DisplayTemplate would be the more appropriate choice. 3 - If you place another parameter on your action method that is a `UserDetailsVM`, does it bind correctly? I would think you would need your `yourVariable.UserDetails.EmailAddress` to bind correctly.

Comment: I suspect the problem lies in something you have not posted.  I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: Is it a typo that you have UserDetailVM and UserDetailsVM?

Comment: Are you sure that your action parameter is called `model`? Could by any chance be called `userDetails`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have added the action

Comment: @Tejs simply because I was not aware of DisplayTemplate, but I will certainly look at using them, sounds useful in my context

Comment: This looks very much like a naming issue of the action argument.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yes, definitely called model, the property on model is called UserDetails however

Comment: Well, then, there must be something else because the code you have shown should work. Try narrowing it down to even simpler example that will allow us to reproduce it. Remove all the noise such as the `TravelHistory` and `ExistingDevices` properties. Simplify everything as much as possible. Are you still getting the same behavior?

Comment: @Tejs - I think EditorTemplate is appropriate.  Typically DisplayTemplate is used for displayed values (they are not in inputs, even if hidden) while EditorTemplate is for things in input attributes (even if hidden), but there is no rule one way or the other.

Comment: I ask again, since it seems to have been lost in the shuffle.  Is it a typo that you have UserDetailsVM in RegistrationVM but have UserDetailVM in the template (note the lack of s on Detail)

Comment: @MystereMan yes sorry that all rather came quickly at once. It is indeed a typo, it should be UserDetailVM for all, I shall edit now

Comment: According to the ModelState error collection it is trying to bind the string 'Foo.Bar.UserDetailVM' to the object (and failing as no type converter exists between string and UserDetailVM)

Comment: You aren't showing us something that is crucial here.  In your attempt to minimize and obfuscate the real code, you are missing something that is crucial to figuring out the problem.

Comment: What is `UserDetailVM` ?

Comment: @asawyer that is a viewmodel that holds information required for the registration process I am trying to implement. The information is gathered from the user in a previous step

Comment: Further information added under Edit3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick background check: this was a problem encountered whilst creating a 'wizard' step by step registration process. I wanted to avoid saving information to the database until the registration was completed. Hence, the idea was to use the TempData collection to store information between Actions, and to use RedirectToAction to move from step to step.

For what it is worth, I amended the method from using TempData like so

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Travel(PreRegistrationVM model)
{
    if (TempData["PreRegistrationVM"] != null)
    {
        model = (PreRegistrationVM)TempData["PreRegistrationVM"];
    }
    var newModel = new RegistrationVM(model);
    return View(newModel);
}
```

To retrieve the information from the database once per step in the registration process.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Travel(int id)
{
    var model = FooRepository.GetById(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why the TempData approach resulted in this, would be interested in people more learned than I offering reasons.

Thanks for all who answered, helped me track it down.